# cumsum() from last entry and moving backward

Tags: r, cumsum

I want to calculate cumulative sum of a vector of numbers from the last value and moving backward. the standard `cumsum()` function in R generally start from the first value and move forward as in simple example -

```
cumsum(1:5)
## 1  3  6 10 15
```

But I want a result like -

```
15, 14, 12, 9, 5
```

Is there any R function to directly calculate that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the solution you are looking for is:

```
rev(cumsum(rev(x)))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
Reduce(sum, 1:5, right = TRUE, accumulate = TRUE)

[1] 15 14 12  9  5
```

Comment: You were faster than me, greetings go out to you!

Comment: wow! sorry I can accept only one as solution. Anyway, many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Another base R option

```
> v <- 1:5

> sum(v) - cumsum(c(0, head(v, -1)))
[1] 15 14 12  9  5
```