# cumulative sum elements

Tags: r

I have:

| id | num |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 4 | 20 |
| 5 | 3 |

and I want to get:

| id | num |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 |
| 2 | 35 |
| 3 | 33 |
| 4 | 23 |
| 5 | 3 |

so: 1 or more, 2 or more ...

Comment: Duplicate of [cumsum() from last entry and moving backward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60760973/cumsum-from-last-entry-and-moving-backward); [Summing at each vector entry to the end of the vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63335905/summing-at-each-vector-entry-to-the-end-of-the-vector); [R cumulative sum, but in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63998757/r-cumulative-sum-but-in-reverse-order);

Comment: e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68658137/filtering-across-multiple-columns-to-get-number-of-rows-in-r/68671087#68671087) is a clear dupe.  So is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68669036/for-loop-using-mutate-comparing-two-data-frames/68669950#68669950). Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or another option would be:

```
library(purrr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(num = accumulate(num, `+`, .dir = "backward"))

  id num
1  1  40
2  2  35
3  3  33
4  4  23
5  5   3
```

Answer (score 4):

In base R you could do this: The logic was first implemented by akrun:

```
df[, 2] <- rev(cumsum(rev(df[, 2])))
```

Output:

```
  id num
1  1  40
2  2  35
3  3  33
4  4  23
5  5   3
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(num = rev(cumsum(rev(num))))
```

-ouptut

```
id num
1  1  40
2  2  35
3  3  33
4  4  23
5  5   3
```

---

Or use

```
library(spatstat.utils)
df1 %>%
    mutate(num = revcumsum(num))
  id num
1  1  40
2  2  35
3  3  33
4  4  23
5  5   3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:5, num = c(5L, 2L, 10L, 20L, 3L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```